# GLFW doesn't initialize on Window using clang

Tags: c, clang, glfw

I was trying to initialize a window using GLFW on Windows 11, but it failed with no error. The code compiled but when I ran it, nothing happened. I compiled GLFW using clang in Visual Studio 17 2022 and compiled the program itself with this command:
`clang -std=c18 -g -IC:\GLFW\include -LC:\GLFW\build\src\Release\ -lglfw3dll .\main.c -o test.exe`

Here's the code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

static void error_callback(int error, const char* description) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s\n", description);
}

int main() {
    glfwSetErrorCallback(error_callback);
    int status = glfwInit();

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CLIENT_API, GLFW_NO_API);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GLFW_FALSE);

    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "Test", NULL, NULL);

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwDestroyWindow(window);

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

Edit: The code works on Fedora 37 btw

Comment: You never call [`glfwMakeContextCurrent(window)`](https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.3/group__context.html#ga1c04dc242268f827290fe40aa1c91157).

Comment: @G.M. I did that and it still didn't work

Answer (score 1):

If I take your code and add the call...

```
glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
```

I get the following error message at the terminal...

> Error: Cannot make current with a window that has no OpenGL or OpenGL
> ES context

Removing the call...

```
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CLIENT_API, GLFW_NO_API);
```

fixes that and the code then behaves as I would expect.  The complete code is now...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

static void error_callback(int error, const char* description) {
  fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s\n", description);
}

int main() {
    glfwSetErrorCallback(error_callback);
    int status = glfwInit();

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GLFW_FALSE);

    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "Test", NULL, NULL);

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwDestroyWindow(window);

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't get anything in the terminal if I add `glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);` and if I remove the line, same thing happens. If I add regular printf() messages before anything else, even those don't print

Comment: I should mention the entire thing works on linux (Fedora 37)